# How to view .mts files on a Mac?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, mts

I am trying to view `.mts` files on a Mac. I can play them fine on Ubuntu using VLC.

However, when I tried VLC player on Mac, the file did not open properly (multiple windows opened up - the voice could be heard but the video was not displayed).

Any useful suggestions would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 2):

## **Final Cut Pro X**

FCPX can work with .mts natively.

> ### <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub>  Supported media formats
>
> You can import and work with the following video, audio, and still-image formats in Final Cut Pro:
>
> **Video formats**
>
> …
>
> - [AVCHD (including AVCCAM, AVCHD Lite, and NXCAM)](http://help.apple.com/finalcutpro/mac/10.0.6/#verb97ce1e7)

<sup>Source: [Final Cut Pro X Help: Supported media formats](http://help.apple.com/finalcutpro/mac/10.0.6/#ver2833f855)</sup>

## VLC Nightly

The [latest nightly build](http://nightlies.videolan.org) of VLC seems to be able to play some .mts files — others just freeze.

## VidConvert

For other cases, I convert them to .mov using [**VidConvert**](http://www.reggieashworth.com/vidconvert).